# PromQL if staement query

Tags: promql

I am trying to set a condition in Prometheus where if the number returns a 0 it should show it as 100.

if ($Positive/$Total)*100 == 0, the it should show it as 100. in a situation where both positive and Total are 0 ?
Thanks in advance